# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException when sending GET to servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi, wildfly-10

I am going throught [this tutorial showing an example of a Stateful EJB](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/java-ee-stateful-session-bean-ejb-example.html). I created a project structure exactly like shown in the tutorial but instead of JPA I am using Hibernate, so I don't have a persitence.xml in StatefulSessionBeansEJB->ejbModule->META-INF but I have a hibernate.cfg.xml in ejbModule. Instead of Glassfish I'm using Wildfly 10 to deploy. Also, after I got the naming exception I added some code to ejb-jar.xml and now it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_2.xsd" version="3.2">

<display-name>StatefulSessionBeansEJB </display-name>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <ejb-name>CartBean</ejb-name>
        <business-local>com.jcg.enterprise.ejb.Cart</business-local>
        <ejb-class>com.jcg.enterprise.ejb.CartBean</ejb-class>
        <session-type>Stateful</session-type>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
  <ejb-client-jar>StatefulSessionBeansEJBClient.jar</ejb-client-jar>
</ejb-jar>
```

At the end of the tutorial there's a url to be used to add a product to the cart:

```
    http://localhost:8080/StatefulSessionBeansTest/ShoppingCartServlet?product=ram
```

When I use it - I get the naming exception which refers to the code in the servlet where JNDI is used to get the resource:

```
cartBean = (Cart) ic.lookup("java:global/StatefulEjbEAR/StatefulSessionBeansEJB/CartBean!"
                                            + "com.jcg.enterprise.ejb.Cart");
```

I don't understand what is the problem here. Can somebody save me time on reading about JNDI? Or is it a Wildfly problem?

Comment: WildFly logs the JNDI names of all the EJBs that it discovers during deployment to the console. Does the name in your `ic.lookup` appear anywhere in the log? Maybe a similar but not identical name?

Comment: Yes, the name does appear in the log but it's different: java:global/StatefulSessionBeansTest/CartBean!com.jcg.enterprise.ejb.Cart. When I used that name in ic.lookup - the error was gone. Now I'm having an issue with hibernate config but that's for another question I guess.

Comment: I recommend that you migrate to the persistence.xml file and use JPA. You can still use Hibernate for this.

Comment: Where did you put JNDI properties please ? can you give us the rest of the code before calling lookup (proxy)